# Trying to run a LoadImpact javascript with edited code

Tags: javascript, random

I have to use LoadImpact to test different parts of my website to make sure they can handle a mass amount of people on them doing different things. LoadImpact lets me go through the process of creating a new user account and records all keystrokes. The issue is that i want to run the same tests over and over, but if the user already exists I am going to see errors. So what i have done is changed the code to apply random names for each test and a random username. What I need to know is will this theoretically work? I haven't used javascript much, but this looks like what should be done to make it work.

```
var first = String.fromCharCode(97 + Math.round(Math.random() * 25));
var second = String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.round(Math.random() * 25));
var firstName = first + second;

var first2 = String.fromCharCode(97 + Math.round(Math.random() * 25));
var second2 = String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.round(Math.random() * 25));
var lastName = first2 + second2;

http.request_batch({
    {"POST", "https://blah.blah.com/registration/lookup/",
        headers = {
            ["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        data = "firstname="+firstName+"&lastname="+lastName+"&dob=02%2F23%2F1980&ssn=4569",
    },
})
http.page_end("Page 5")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one big problem with that script - Load Impact scripting is done in [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), not Javascript!

The code should look something like this:

```
local first = String.char(97 + Math.random(25))
local second = String.char(65 + Math.random(25))
local firstName = first .. second

local first2 = String.char(97 + Math.random(25))
local second2 = String.char(65 + Math.random(25))
local lastName = first2 .. second2

http.request_batch({
    {"POST", "https://blah.blah.com/registration/lookup/",
        headers = {
            ["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        data = "firstname=" .. firstName .. "&lastname=" .. lastName .. "&dob=02%2F23%2F1980&ssn=459",
    },
})
```